# Victory react native animations are not working inside Animated.FlatList when passed inside renderItem

Tags: react-native, animation, react-native-flatlist, flatlist, victory-charts

Trying to render multiple victory charts using react native animated flatlist but the animations/transitions don't seem to be working as expected. everything else is working fine. Animations/transitions of the chart are working perfectly fine if the same chart is placed outside of flatlist.
Also, there is a tooltip in the chart which should appear on tap and drag, but the drag interaction is not working, putting the chart outside flatlist, tap and drag action works fine.

[refer img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gb0sD.png)

This is what my flatlist code looks like

```
const swipeListener = (event: NativeSyntheticEvent<NativeScrollEvent>) => {
    event.persist();
    if (event.nativeEvent !== null) {
      const contentOffset = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset;
      const viewSize = event.nativeEvent.layoutMeasurement;
      currentSlide.current = Math.round(contentOffset.x / viewSize.width);
      if (prevSlide.current !== currentSlide.current) {
        setCurrPage(currentSlide.current);
      }
      prevSlide.current = currentSlide.current;
    }
  };


  const scrollX = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;          


<Animated.FlatList
            onScroll={Animated.event([{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { x: scrollX } } }], {
              useNativeDriver: true,
              listener: swipeListener,
            })}
            bounces={false}
            ref={flatListRef}
            horizontal
            decelerationRate="fast"
            directionalLockEnabled
            disableIntervalMomentum
            snapToAlignment="center"
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            snapToInterval={windowWidth - 40}
            keyExtractor={(_, index) => index.toString()}
            initialScrollIndex={data.length - 1}
            scrollEventThrottle={64}
            pagingEnabled
            data={data}
            renderItem={d => (
              <VictoryChart index={d} />   
            )}
          />
```

Not able to find any solution related to this issue, it would be helpful if someone can nudge me into the right direction.